# iText 7 exception during convert html to pdf using itext : Default value of the css property "text-decoration-thickness" is unknown

Tags: itext7, html2pdf

Iam using Itext7 to convert html to pdf using HtmlConverter, and here is the html2pdf dependecy. Iam getting the following error in the log.

```
ERROR com.itextpdf.styledxmlparser.css.resolve.CssDefaults - Default value of the css property "text-decoration-thickness" is unknown.

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>`enter code here`
   <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>

sample html:

<head></head><body>
<p style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Times New Roman&quot;; font-size: 16px; font-style: normal; font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; text-decoration-thickness: initial; text-decoration-style: initial; text-decoration-color: initial; text-align: left; break-inside: auto; break-after: auto; break-before: avoid; line-height: normal; margin: 14pt 0pt; text-indent: 36pt; border-left-style: hidden; border-right-style: hidden;">
<span lang="en-US" style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: 11pt; text-transform: none; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; text-decoration: none;">
sample html with text-decoration-thickness warning in html2pdf conversion
</span>
</p>
</body>
```

Comment: sometimes getting the other errors like:   ERROR c.i.s.c.p.CssRuleSetParser Invalid css property declaration: "Times New Roman",serif

Comment: ERROR c.i.s.c.p.CssRuleSetParser Invalid css property declaration: justify

Comment: ERROR c.i.s.c.p.CssRuleSetParser Invalid css property declaration: 14.0pt

Answer (score 0):

you can try your test on [the demo lab](https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/convert-html-css-to-pdf-free-online). if it does not work on the demo lab, it is not supported.

Comment: Thank You.  I have tested on the demo lab and had the same issue.